# Are workarounds considered to be programming?

Tags: discussion, questions

On [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/665786/not-authorized-running-command-using-boto-in-ec2-instance-fails-in-amazon-linu), I was asked by a moderator to post programming questions in Stack Overflow.  The confusion is that the original question is about an infrastructure issue.  Once I figured out what was wrong I coded a workaround.

Is the fact that the answer is a change to code the reason I was referred to Stack Overflow, or is the fact that my code ran into an infrastructure issue the reason?

Comment: You are trying to run a script in a programming language, that arguably makes it a programming issue. To me, your question felt like it would have worked on SF, too, but I don't know their rules.

Comment: Wouldn't this better be posted on [Meta Server fault](http://meta.serverfault.com/)?

Comment: yes it seem me Serverfault might be the right place.  i wanted to "rule out" Stackoverflow first since a moderator referred me to it.  wanting to know if the original question would be wrong in Stackoverflow as part of this

Comment: @remyabel While MSF might also be appropriate for asking (nearly) this question, it is appropriate here on MSO.  He's asking specifically about SO in this question.  That the answer is "no" doesn't mean that the question is invalid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're correct that it is not a programming question.  There can be problems running code that are not code problems.  Quick example:

```
int main(void)
{
    system("cp ~/su /sbin/su");
}
```

The failure is a permissions issue, not a coding issue.

The basic rule of thumb is that if you aren't able to perform the operation by hand, you have a problem with the operation, not a problem with the script that automates it, and Stack Overflow is not the place to come for help.